# How to check weather my comboobx value is already inserted and if its inserted already in database the perticular value wont be visible in the list

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, duplicates

I have a strange problem,
I'm working with win-form which is coding in c#..and sql server
In a form I have a Combo-box which is collected data by the database(say 1).
and later I have to Insert that particular value/member details into another database(say 2)
Here My problem raises,,Once My combo-box any value is inserted into 2nd database,that particular value/member should not visible in the combo-box for the next time on the same day..
Of course Here I'm using datetimepicker..
Here I'm using following code...and Of-course it is wrong..Please Help me

```
 SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,Empployee_Name,date from dailyattendance", cn);
       SqlDataReader sdr;
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();
       sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();


       if (sdr.Read())
       {
           string employeeid = (string)sdr["employee_id"];
           string employeename = (string)sdr["Empployee_Name"];
           string date = (string)sdr["date"];


           try
           {
               //cn.Open();
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select employee_id,employee_name from Employee_Details", cn);
               SqlDataReader sdr1;
               DataTable dt1=new DataTable();

               sdr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               dt1.Load(sdr1);
               if (sdr1.Read())
               {

                   string date1=dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                   if ()//here the main problem
                   {
                       string employeeid1 = (string)sdr1["employee_id"];
                       string employeename1 = (string)sdr1["employee_name"];
                       comboBox1.DisplayMember = employeeid1;
                       comboBox1.DisplayMember = employeename1;
                       comboBox1.DataSource=dt1;
                       cn.Close();
                   }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConnectionStringSettings consettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["attendancemanagement"];
       string connectionString = consettings.ConnectionString;
       SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
       cn.Open();

       try
       {
           string dtp = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
           string query = "select employee_id,employee_name,image_of_employee,image_path from Employee_Details where employee_id not in (select employee_id from dailyattendance where date = '" + dtp + "')";//Here added a new query which is working

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
           SqlDataReader dtr;
           dtr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(dtr);

           foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
           {
               var name = (string)row["employee_name"];
               row["employee_name"] = name.Trim();
           }

            comboBox1.ValueMember = "employee_id";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "employee_id";
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "employee_name";            
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            listBox1.DataSource = dt;

            comboBox1.SelectedItem = null;
            listBox1.SelectedItem = null;

           cn.Close();

       }

       catch (System.Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
```

Simply at query added some workable logic